# jquery validation with regular expression submit issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

What is wrong with the following code? The error message is shown but the form got submitted. Is it due to update panel as the control is inside asp.net update panel.

```
   $.validator.addMethod("regex",
               function (value, element, regexp) {
                   var re = new RegExp(regexp);
                   return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
               }


             );

               $("#mainForm").validate({

                   rules: {

                       "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
                           required: true,
                        regex: /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
                    }

                },
                   messages: {

                       "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
                           regex: "invalid format"
                       }
                   },
                   onsubmit: false,

               });
```

I solved the problem but another problem poped up. The second time when the drop down value is change it doesn't work. Seems like it set the fixedPortion only one time.

```
    <script>
     function fn_init() {
        $.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            //alert(regexp);
            // return this.optional(element) || What is this line doing
            //alert(re.test(value));
            return re.test(value); // Just test that it passes regex
        }, '');

        //^SPI-[\da-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,10} [a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,20} \d{4}$
        var fixedPortion = new RegExp("^SPI-" + $("#ddlLOB option:selected").text() + " [\\da-zA-Z''-'\\s]{1,20} \\d{4}$");
       // alert(fixedPortion);
        $("#mainForm").validate({

            rules: {
                "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
                    required: true,
                    regex:fixedPortion
                       // regex: /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
                    }

                },
                messages: {

                    "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
                        regex: "invalid format"
                    }
                },
            showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {

                // Clean up any tooltips for valid elements
                $.each(this.validElements(), function (index, element) {
                    var $element = $(element);

                    $element.data("title", "") // Clear the title - there is no error associated anymore
                        .removeClass("validatorCalloutHighlight");

                });

                // Create new tooltips for invalid elements
                $.each(errorList, function (index, error) {
                    var $element = $(error.element);

                    $element.addClass("validatorCalloutHighlight");
                    //$element.tooltip("destroy") // Destroy any pre-existing tooltip so we can repopulate with new tooltip content
                    //    .data("title", error.message)
                    //    .addClass("error")
                    //    .tooltip(); // Create a new tooltip based on the error messsage we just set in the title
                });
            }


        });
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_initializeRequest(onEachRequest);
        function onEachRequest(sender, args) {
            if ($("#mainForm").valid() == false) {
                args.set_cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(function () {

            fn_init();

           });
          }
```

Comment: What error do you get? Press F12 in the browser to see the console.

Comment: No errors. i checked with f12

Comment: Did you refresh the page with the console active? Else there will be no data to display ;) - You can put alerts between with data to see what information is stored or if the function is called at all.

Comment: What's the ID of the input field you're trying to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I just removed the onsubmit property. I suggest you just test the regex alone and not whatever you have before it.

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function (value, element, regexp) {
        var re = new RegExp(regexp);
        var value = $('#txtContractName').val();
        // return this.optional(element) || What is this line doing
        return re.test(value); // Just test that it passes regex
    }, '');

$("#mainForm").validate({
    rules: {
        "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
            required: true,
            regex: /^[2-9]\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "<%= txtContractName.UniqueID %>": {
            regex: "invalid format"
        }
    }
});
```

### Update

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/ZT77L/)**

Comment: when i removed the focus out of textbox the validation is fired (false when input is wrong true when it is correct). but when i click the submit when the validation is not fired.

Comment: give me a valid input to test. let me check it here

Comment: Nope. The page is submitted even though the input is wrong. Type anything other than number which is invalid input. valid: 333-333-3333

Comment: Yes its working. But what could be the problem my case?

Comment: The controls are inside asp.net update panel? could this be issue?

Comment: Probably, can you move it out?